# How to check if the current user has the right to create a DDL trigger on the current database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the information about permissions for the current user using:

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(DB_NAME(), 'DATABASE', 'CREATE TABLE')

SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(DB_NAME(), 'DATABASE', 'CREATE PROCEDURE')
```

and this is working fine.

What is the correct syntax for CREATE TRIGGER?

I've tried :

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(DB_NAME(), 'DATABASE', 'CREATE TRIGGER')
```

and few variations with no luck. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CREATE TRIGGER` permission does not exist.

Check the [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to view the required permissions that lets to use `CREATE TRIGGER`.

> To create a DML trigger requires ALTER permission on the table or view
> on which the trigger is being created.
>
> To create a DDL trigger with
> server scope (ON ALL SERVER) or a logon trigger requires CONTROL
> SERVER permission on the server. To create a DDL trigger with database
> scope (ON DATABASE) requires ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER permission
> in the current database.

Comment: I was going to post the exact same thing :-)

Comment: Thanks. Putting ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER instead of CREATE TRIGGER did the trick.